# tabularx and tablefootnote multiple footnotes from one \tablefootnote

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularx

In my tablularx environment I have a footnote that I'd like to have placed at the bottom of the page. 
Using both the `tabularx` and `tablefootnote` packages all is well. However I get served a bit too much.
Please find the code I use attached aswell as the result

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{a4wide}
    \usepackage{eurosym}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{tablefootnote}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
      \centering
      \caption[Firm Details]{Firm Details. Source Author}
      \label{tab:firmsDescriptions}
       \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{1.1\textwidth}{lXXXX} 
     % \toprule

     \textbf{FirmName}           & CapGemini      & T-Systems & WiPro &Infosys\\

     \textbf{Economy}  & DE  & DE  & EE  & EE\\

     \textbf{Industry Type}     & ICT Services     & ICT Services & ICT Services & ICT Services\\

     \textbf{Home Country}    & France             & Germany & India& India\\

     \textbf{Employees}          & 100.000+       &  48.000 & 135.000 &150,000+\\

     \textbf{Revenue}             & \euro~10Bn    & \euro~9Bn & \euro 4.6Bn
     &\euro 5.6Bn\tablefootnote{original figure in US\$~(7.4Bn) recalculated using exchange rate USD EUR of 1.3 } \\
     \textbf{Description}  \textbf{Description}   Capgemini is a listed company at the Euronext stock exchange in Paris. The  main business of Capgemini are ICT and consulting services. The latter was acquired via a takeover of Ernst\& Young Consulting. The name came to be from a merger between CAP, Sogeti and Gemini inc. Now Sogeti is wholly owned daughter of Capgemini. Typical clients are found in large manufacturing companies, banking and insurance, but also the public sector and healthcare.  &

 T-systems is a subsidiary of Deutsche Telekom AG. Although a subsidiary it does serve other customers than DT. The main activities are IT consulting and IT services. These include minting the IT application landscape and building new applications specific for the client. Typical clients are found in large manufacturing companies, banking and insurance, but also the public sector.&

 WiPro is an Indian ICT services company, that unlike others started of as an company that manufactured oils, soaps and waxes as the `Western India Vegetable Products' This heritage is still maintained in its company logo of a sunflower. In 1981 WiPro diversifies into IT services. The business is now known for.  
Their main clients other MNE that are located in the financial services, healthcare, manufacturing and telecommunications domains.&

 In 1981 Infosys Consultants was established. In 1992 the name was changes to Infosys Technologies. Infosys is a NYSE listed global consulting and IT services company stemming from India. Similar to other Indian IT services firms the clients are MNE that are located in the financial services, healthcare, manufacturing and telecommunications domains \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

To my supprise this is my result

[image: tablefootnote]

How do i get rid of the -1 and 0 footnotes?
I thought I have defined just the one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see the problem is `tabularx` because it tries to find out the best width for the table.  That's the reason you get 3 different footnotes instead the wanted one.

I do not know package `tabularx` well so it could be, that there is a solution described in it's documentation.

As an workaround change `tabularx` to `tabular` and everything is working as wanted, see following MWE.  BTW I did a little bit pretty printing with your table and changed the order calling your packages.  As far as I know is package `a4wide` obsolet (see l2tabu, `texdoc l2tabu`).

MWE deleted, see MWE2 below.

EDIT:

With you new description added to your question it seems you will have long tables.  So consider using package `longtable`.  I changed my MWE and added a table version with `tabular` and `longtable`. Package `longtable` does not need package `` tablefootnote`.

MWE2:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

With the known error:    
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption[Firm Details]{Firm Details. Source Author}
  \label{tab:firmsDescriptions}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{1.1\textwidth}{p{2.5cm}XXXX} 
    \textbf{FirmName}      & CapGemini    & T-Systems    & WiPro        & Infosys\\
    \textbf{Economy}       & DE           & DE           & EE           & EE\\
    \textbf{Industry Type} & ICT Services & ICT Services & ICT Services & ICT Services\\
    \textbf{Home Country}  & France       & Germany      & India        & India\\
    \textbf{Employees}     & 100.000+     &  48.000      & 135.000      & 150,000+\\
    \textbf{Revenue}       & \euro~10Bn   & \euro~9Bn    & \euro 4.6Bn
    &\euro 5.6Bn\tablefootnote{original figure in US\$~(7.4Bn) recalculated using exchange rate USD EUR of 1.3 } \\
    \textbf{Description}   & Capgemini is a listed company at the Euronext stock exchange in Paris. The  main business of Capgemini are ICT and consulting services. The latter was acquired via a takeover of Ernst\& Young Consulting. The name came to be from a merger between CAP, Sogeti and Gemini inc. Now Sogeti is wholly owned daughter of Capgemini. Typical clients are found in large manufacturing companies, banking and insurance, but also the public sector and healthcare.  &

 T-systems is a subsidiary of Deutsche Telekom AG. Although a subsidiary it does serve other customers than DT. The main activities are IT consulting and IT services. These include minting the IT application landscape and building new applications specific for the client. Typical clients are found in large manufacturing companies, banking and insurance, but also the public sector.&

 WiPro is an Indian ICT services company, that unlike others started of as an company that manufactured oils, soaps and waxes as the `Western India Vegetable Products' This heritage is still maintained in its company logo of a sunflower. In 1981 WiPro diversifies into IT services. The business is now known for.  
Their main clients other MNE that are located in the financial services, healthcare, manufacturing and telecommunications domains.&

 In 1981 Infosys Consultants was established. In 1992 the name was changes to Infosys Technologies. Infosys is a NYSE listed global consulting and IT services company stemming from India. Similar to other Indian IT services firms the clients are MNE that are located in the financial services, healthcare, manufacturing and telecommunications domains \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption[Firm Details]{Firm Details. Source Author}
  \label{tab:Descriptions}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}} 
    \textbf{FirmName}      & CapGemini    & T-Systems    & WiPro        & Infosys\\
    \textbf{Economy}       & DE           & DE           & EE           & EE\\
    \textbf{Industry Type} & ICT Services & ICT Services & ICT Services & ICT Services\\
    \textbf{Home Country}  & France       & Germany      & India        & India\\
    \textbf{Employees}     & 100.000+     &  48.000      & 135.000      & 150,000+\\
    \textbf{Revenue}       & \euro~10Bn   & \euro~9Bn    & \euro 4.6Bn
    &\euro 5.6Bn\tablefootnote{original figure in US\$~(7.4Bn) recalculated using exchange rate USD EUR of 1.3 } \\
    \textbf{Description}   & Capgemini is a listed company at the Euronext stock exchange in Paris. The  main business of Capgemini are ICT and consulting services. The latter was acquired via a takeover of Ernst\& Young Consulting. The name came to be from a merger between CAP, Sogeti and Gemini inc. Now Sogeti is wholly owned daughter of Capgemini. Typical clients are found in large manufacturing companies, banking and insurance, but also the public sector and healthcare.  &

 T-systems is a subsidiary of Deutsche Telekom AG. Although a subsidiary it does serve other customers than DT. The main activities are IT consulting and IT services. These include minting the IT application landscape and building new applications specific for the client. Typical clients are found in large manufacturing companies, banking and insurance, but also the public sector.&

 WiPro is an Indian ICT services company, that unlike others started of as an company that manufactured oils, soaps and waxes as the `Western India Vegetable Products' This heritage is still maintained in its company logo of a sunflower. In 1981 WiPro diversifies into IT services. The business is now known for.  
Their main clients other MNE that are located in the financial services, healthcare, manufacturing and telecommunications domains.&

 In 1981 Infosys Consultants was established. In 1992 the name was changes to Infosys Technologies. Infosys is a NYSE listed global consulting and IT services company stemming from India. Similar to other Indian IT services firms the clients are MNE that are located in the financial services, healthcare, manufacturing and telecommunications domains \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage
{\footnotesize
\rowcolors[]{2}{white}{blue!10}
\begin{longtable}{>{\bfseries\RaggedRight}p{2cm}>{\RaggedRight}p{3cm}>{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}}
  \caption[Firm Details]{Firm Details. Source Author}
  \label{tab:Descriptions}\\

  FirmName      & CapGemini    & T-Systems    & WiPro        & Infosys      \\
  Economy       & DE           & DE           & EE           & EE           \\
  Industry Type & ICT Services & ICT Services & ICT Services & ICT Services \\
  Home Country  & France       & Germany      & India        & India        \\
  Employees     & 100.000+     &  48.000      & 135.000      & 150,000+     \\
  Revenue       & \euro~10Bn   & \euro~9Bn    & \euro 4.6Bn  & 
    \euro 5.6Bn\footnote{original figure in US\$~(7.4Bn) recalculated using exchange rate USD EUR of 1.3} \\
  Description   & Capgemini is a listed company at the Euronext stock exchange in Paris. The  main business of Capgemini are ICT and consulting services. The latter was acquired via a takeover of Ernst\& Young Consulting. The name came to be from a merger between CAP, Sogeti and Gemini inc. Now Sogeti is wholly owned daughter of Capgemini. Typical clients are found in large manufacturing companies, banking and insurance, but also the public sector and healthcare.  
                               & T-systems is a subsidiary of Deutsche Telekom AG. Although a subsidiary it does serve other customers than DT. The main activities are IT consulting and IT services. These include minting the IT application landscape and building new applications specific for the client. Typical clients are found in large manufacturing companies, banking and insurance, but also the public sector.
                                              & WiPro is an Indian ICT services company, that unlike others started of as an company that manufactured oils, soaps and waxes as the `Western India Vegetable Products' This heritage is still maintained in its company logo of a sunflower. In 1981 WiPro diversifies into IT services. The business is now known for.  
Their main clients other MNE that are located in the financial services, healthcare, manufacturing and telecommunications domains. 
                                                             & In 1981 Infosys Consultants was established. In 1992 the name was changes to Infosys Technologies. Infosys is a NYSE listed global consulting and IT services company stemming from India. Similar to other Indian IT services firms the clients are MNE that are located in the financial services, healthcare, manufacturing and telecommunications domains \\
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does work for the table to be displayed correctly. However now I still get the triple footnotes....

Comment: Hadn't thought of just plain telling Latex what to do i.s.o. having latex figuring this out it self.